# How to add a row datagridview data-bound control by a module

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, module, row, addition

In my project I had to create a module, lets say it's name is "intjobs.vb",
and I want to call a sub in it which is called `dorow`.

Here is the module:

```
 Module intjobs

    Public Sub dorow(fldtype, fldid, flddlvl)


      Dim fdt As New dataTDataSet.fieldsDataTable
      Dim dr As DataRow = fdt.NewRow
      dr.Item(0) = "del"
      dr.Item(1) = "up"
      dr.Item(2) = "down"
      dr.Item(3) = fldtype
      dr.Item(4) = False
      dr.Item(5) = fldid.ToString
      dr.Item(6) = flddlvl.ToString
      fdt.Rows.Add(dr)
      'Dim log As String = "Sub name: dorow {somevalue}"
      'logger(2, log)
  End Sub
End Module
```

So when I put this sub in the same windows form with the datagridview, it works perfectly, 
but it doesn't add any row when I use this module.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the right **Modifier**:

1. Set the **Modifier** of the grid view as **Public**.
2. In the *Module* use a code similar to this:

   ```
   Public Sub Modify_Cross_Module(ByRef DataGrid As DataGridView, _
                              ByVal firstColumnVal As String, _
                              ByVal secondColumnVal As String)

   DataGrid.Rows.Add(firstColumnVal, secondColumnVal)
   End Sub
   ```

You have to make sure that the **DataGrid** variable as ***ByRef***.

***When*** you call that sub, use the following code:

```
Modify_Cross_Module(DataGridView1, "FirstVal", "SecondVal")
```

Where **DataGridView1** is the DataGridView you want to add row to it.

Comment: uh,
i just had one problem,
that is i have 2 windows forms
the first is Main
and second called OPT
so form OPT is calling the sub in the module
but form Main is that one which contains the DataGridView
so the sub must be called by the main form
i just tried to add a little sub to the main form which only calls the sub in this module
sorry for abusing this
but if you know another method, am just trying to keep the main form clear
thanks again

Comment: You're welcome... Actually, I didn't understand what are you trying to do. What do you mean by **OPT**? What I understood: _you_ have two forms, **Form1** calls **Form2**. **Form1** contains the datagridview. You need to add row to that datagridview in **Form1** by an order from **Form2**, _is that what you trying to do?_

Comment: thats it,
so as i said i just added a sub wich redirects the call of the module from Form1 into Form2,
means in Form2 btn_click calls public sub in Form1
public sub in Form1 calls Modify_Cross_Module
but i should keep Form1 clear if i can

Comment: Here is my advice: keeping the form clean does not mean to shatter its objects (functions and subroutines), you start to divide the code in two main cases: **When** the GUI starts to be crowded or out of the familiar look to the users, you would divide the GUI itself into multiple forms, and **When** there is a need to use the same object in different classes and modules. **_Shattering_** your code make it harder to deal with it, and it would be clean for your eyes only, but to the processor, it would be more waste of time to keep calling and moving through threads. Greetings!